# How can i receive a FormData with a file and string appended in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I've this code in JS i am sending an XHR post request to the php file how to handle getting the file and the string in PHP?

I am gonna use the string to create a path like "Code/Math" then move file to that path.

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#Upload').click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        var url = 'uploadFile.php';
        var file = $("#file");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData.append('File',file[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('Path','/Upload/Upload');
        xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
            var percent = (Math.floor(done / total * 1000) / 10) + '%';
            $('#uploadprogress').css('width', percent+'%');
        }, false);

        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                var percent = (Math.floor(done / total * 1000) / 10) + '%';
            };
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
            if (4 == this.readyState) {
                $('#message').text(e.currentTarget.response);
                $('#uploadprogress').css('width', '0%');
                $('#file').val('');
            }
        };

        xhr.open('post', url, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });

    var progressHandling = function(e){
        if(e.lengthComputable){
            var percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            $('#uploadprogress').css('width', percent+'%');
        }
    };

    var completeHandler = function(data){
        $('#message').text(data);
        $('#uploadprogress').css('width', '0%');
        $('#file').val('');
    };
});
```

Comment: I'd guess you would receive them just like any other posted key/value pair data.

Comment: If it was just the file i'd use $_FILES but i am sending a string as well. do i use $_Post?

Comment: I don't know, i'm not too familiar with php. I would expect the string you passed to be in $_POST. Think of it as a `<form>` with `<input>`'s

Comment: I don't know either i am new to php, i guess it's not solved.

Comment: Ok this worked $_FILES["File"] for file & $_Post["Path"] for string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling ajax requests on the server, think of the ajax as nothing more than a form submit. You handle it exactly the same way as if it were a form. For a POST request, the parameters will be available in `$_POST`, `$_GET` for get requests, and files will be under `$_FILES`. there are exceptions though depending on how exactly the ajax request was formed/sent, because it is possible to post data in the request body rather than as parameters, however that doesn't really apply to your case.

**TL;DR:**

use `$_POST["Path"]` and `$_FILES["File"]`